# QRCode package fails to convert to HTML

Tags: htlatex, rendering, qrcode

I'm using the [CTAN QRcode package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en).

It works great with PDF, but unfortunately doesn't work at all for HTML.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or how I can force htlatex to use images for the QR codes?

pdflatex output:
[image: pdflatex qrcode]

htlatex output viewed in Firefox:
[image: htlatex qrcode]

TeX:

```
\section{Data}


\subsection{Electrum seed}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{c}
\qrcode[height=1.5in,padding]{hawk pigeon horn badge amount engine math convince rural farm inhale mandate absorb} \newline
\end{longtable}
\LARGE{hawk pigeon horn badge amount engine math convince rural farm inhale mandate absorb}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 3):

`tex4ht` doesn't have configuration for `\qrcode`, but it is quite easy to make one. Configurations for packages are provided in `packagename.4ht` files, `qrcode.4ht` in our case:

```
\let\oldqrcode=\qrcode

\NewConfigure{qrcode}{2}

\renewcommand\qrcode[2][]{%
\a:qrcode%
\oldqrcode[#1]{#2}%
\b:qrcode%
}

\Configure{qrcode}
{\Picture+{}}
{\EndPicture}
```

first, old definition of `\qrcode` is saved, then configurable hooks named `qrcode` are declared, and `\qrcode` is redefined to insert hooks `\a:qrcode` and `\b:qrcode` around saved old contents of `\qrcode`.

The hooks are then configured with `\Configure{qrcode}`, `\Picture+` and `\EndPicture` commands render content which is inside as image:

[image]

Comment: I was about to accept this answer but it has a huge problem: spaces are omitted in the `htlatex` output, scanning the code in your answer gives `hawkpigeonhornbadgeamountenginemathconvinceruralfarminhalemandateabsorb` while scanning the pdflatex code gives `hawk pigeon horn badge amount engine math convince rural farm inhale mandate absorb`. I replicated it on my machine too :( (If you do not have a smartphone with which to scan, you can use the command `import :- | zbarimg :-`)

This answer will only work if your QR data contains no spaces.